# Replacing string at certain index of Split

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio-2010

Using streamreader to read line by line of a text file. When I get to a certain line (i.e., 123|abc|99999||ded||789), I want to replace ONLY the first empty area with text.

So far, I've been toying with

```
If sLine.Split("|")(3) = "" Then
    'This is where I'm stuck, I want to replace that index with mmm
End If
```

I want the output to look like this:     123|abc|99999|mmm|ded||789

Comment: What if the line already looks like, "123|abc|99999|mmm|ded||789", then what?

Comment: I have a conditional that skips it

Comment: But if a line that you read in looks like, "123|abc|99999|mmm|ded||789", would the result of what you're wanting be, 123|abc|99999|mmm|ded|789"?

Comment: No, I want it to only update the first instance of ||, all others to remain the same/ignored. So 123|abc|99999|mmm|ded||789 not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the string, modify the array and rejoin it to recreate the string:

```
Dim sLine = "123|abc|99999||ded||789"
Dim parts = sLine.Split("|")
If parts(3) = "" Then
    parts(3) = "mmm"
    sLine = String.Join("|", parts)
End If
```

Comment: So what about if parts(3) doesn't equal String.Empty?

Comment: @Shar1er80 In that case, the string will end up being the same as the initial value.  Probably should move the `String.Join` inside the `If` to save that work - I'll update the code.

Comment: So what if the line that is read from the file looks like 123||abc|99999|ded||789?

Comment: @Shar1er80 Then the result will be `123||abc|99999|ded||789` - i.e. the string will not be modified since it does not meet the condition being checked for.

Comment: Then you haven't replaced the first empty area with text, as the OP stated, "I want to replace ONLY the first empty area with text."

Comment: @Shar1er80 The question is not entirely clear on what the OP wants.  The code sample is hard-coded to replace the 4th segment, and the title is "Replacing string at certain index of Split", so that's what I went with.  The "I want to replace ONLY the first empty area with text" from the question could be referring to the sample data, where segments 4 and 6 are empty, but they only want to replace segment 4.  Only the OP can clear up the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Considering you already have code determining if the "mmm" string needs to be added or not, you could use the following:

```
Dim index As Integer = sLine.IndexOf("||")
sLine = sLine.Insert(index + 1, "mmm")
```

Answer (score 2):

I gather that if you find one or more empty elements, you want to replace the first empty element with data and leave the rest blank.  You can accomplish this by splitting on the pipe to get an array of strings, iterate through the array and replace the first empty element you come across and exit the loop, and then rejoin your array.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim data As String = "123||abc|99999||ded||789"
    Dim parts = data.Split("|")
    For index = 0 To parts.Length - 1
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(parts(index)) Then
            parts(index) = "mmm"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    data = String.Join("|", parts)
    Console.WriteLine(data)
End Sub
```

Results:

```
123|mmm|abc|99999||ded||789
```